# Why does this take so long time to run?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

How do you improve the speed of this? It took me more than 10 minutes and is still running.

 I want to gather them in pair of inverse elements.

```
states = Tuples[{True, False}, {16}]
Gather[states, ((Not /@ #1) == #2) &]
```

Comment: I think that the reason is that `states // Length` yields `65536`.

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 do you have any idea to do it faster?

Comment: not on the top of my head. perhaps useful links: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215075/effectively-gather-data-with-small-differences

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179042/gathering-a-list-efficiently

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 I think there are some ways to generate the pairs without doing Gather but I'm not exactly know how to do it.

Answer (score 10):

You can generate all such pairs by using their symmetry

```
pairs[n_]:={{True,Sequence@@#},{False,Sequence@@(Not/@#)}}&/@Tuples[{True,False},{n-1}];
```

This leads to the same result as your code

```
gatheredStates[n_]:= Gather[Tuples[{True, False}, {n}], ((Not /@ #1) == #2) &];

pairs[10] === gatheredStates[10]
(* True *)
```

though much faster

```
RepeatedTiming[pairs[16];]
(* 0.18793 sec *)
```

Comment: Using `0` and `1` in place of `False` and `True` makes things just a little faster (about 15% faster):  `pairs[n_] := {{1, Sequence @@ #}, {0, Sequence @@ (1 - #)}} & /@ Tuples[{1, 0}, {n - 1}];`.

Answer (score 9):

As an example, here are the binary numbers from 0 to 7:

[image]

Counting and pairing these up as shown above would achieve the same result when converted to Boolean values.

```
binpairs[n_] := {IntegerDigits[2^n - # - 1, 2, n], 
     IntegerDigits[#, 2, n]} & /@ 
   Range[0, 2^(n - 1) - 1] /. {1 -> True, 0 -> False}
```

To compare equivalence with the answer by @Hausdorff:

```
binpairs[16] == pairs[16]
```

> `(*True*)`

---

An advantage of using binary numbers is that each pair in the list is deterministic: i.e., Nothing needs to be pre-computed or stored.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an alternative approach using `0` and `1` rather than `False` and `True`:

```
pairs[n_] := Module[{t},
  t = Tuples[{0, 1}, {n}];
  t = Transpose[{t, 1 - t}];
  t = DeleteDuplicates[Sort[#] & /@ t]]

pairs[4]
(* {{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0}}, 
    {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}}, 
    {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}}, {{0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}}, 
    {{0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}}} *)

RepeatedTiming[pairs[16];]
(* {0.100445, Null} *)
```

Stealing directly from @Syed 's answer only the first half of the tuples need to be examined which is must faster:

```
pairs[n_] := Module[{t},
  t = Tuples[{0, 1}, {n}][[1 ;; 2^(n - 1)]];
  t = Transpose[{t, 1 - t}]]

pairs[4]
(* {{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0}}, 
    {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}}, 
    {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}}, {{0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}},
    {{0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}}} *)

RepeatedTiming[pairs[16];]
(* {0.0141504, Null} *)
```